# Google Apps Script: Compare One Cell to Another, then Increment Cell Value

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, spreadsheet, google-docs

I'm not very experienced in programming, but I'm looking to do something specific with my Google Sheets document.  As an example:

- I buy fruit buy the box.  Each type of box has a
  certain amount of each fruit.
- My customers have standing orders for
  differing numbers of certain fruit platters I sell.
- I need to figure
  how many of each fruit box I need to buy to fulfil each customer's
  order, with a minimum of wastage.

I keep running into circular dependancy errors when I try to work things out with my limited spreadsheet knowledge.  Ideally what I'd like to do is have a script that:

- Increments the "Amount to Buy" of Fruit Box #1 by 100 (they come in pallets of 100, I can't buy less)
- If the amount of fruit with the best yield for that box (highlighted in green on the "Fruit Boxes" sheet.  Fruit Box #1 is Cherry) is met, then the sheet moves onto the next fruit box.

At the moment I am able to get the sheet to tell me how much of each fruit box I need to buy to have enough of the "best yield" fruit that box contains, but I need it to take into account that the other boxes I need to buy also may contain some of that fruit.

My example sheet is here >> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tbI89jfY2ddAlyTN5VGaQ3nSRsgJcuR6Ev3I-YIdUoA/edit?usp=sharing

**Note:**  Bonus points for anyone who can suggest a better way of displaying how many of each platter each customer requires.  At the moment I'm using a very long and clunky **IF, THEN** statement in the "Required" column for each fruit platter, but I'm sure there must be a better way.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a Google Apps *script* question - are you planning to code a solution in Javascript, or are you happy to just use normal spreadsheet functions? I suspect the later, in which case you may be better off asking in https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets

Some functions that may be relevant to explore include SUMIF, SUMPRODUCT, HLOOKUP and VLOOKUP. I'm not sure I fully understand your question so I can't help you more!